# Expected IV length 0 error in AES 128 Decypt

Tags: java, android, aes, caesar-cipher

I know a lot of these questions were asked. but in my case the error is:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: expected IV length of 0
```

I'm trying AES 128 CBC mode

code:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[]{(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00
                            , (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};

        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return decryptedBytes;
```

If I change init vector to something like this as error suggested:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[]{};
```

I'm receiving error :

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: expected IV length of 16
```

Answer (score 0):

For CBC mode you should call

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

`NoPadding` options means that apply no padding. This is useful if

- Your data is always multiple of the AES block size, i.e. 128k
- You will do your padding, probably developing a new one.

If you are talking about ECB mode, that doesn't need IV and don't use ECB. It is insecure. If you really need then call it without an IV.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
```

If your Android target matches prefer GCM mode instead of ECB or CBC. That is a modern encryption mode; Authenticated Encryption (with Associated Data). You will get Confidentiality, authentication, and integrity.

Comment: Changed as suggested but now throwing this error: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: EVP_CipherFinal_ex

Comment: Also my data will be always 128 bit, 128-bit key and IV

Comment: encyption is done by NFC based card reader (I'm using this for card auth). I will receive 16-byte encrypted data with the key.

Comment: As per doc 'encrypted/decrypted using AES 128 CBC with
an IV with value 00h'

Comment: I have NDA signed for the doc. I cant share link or its copy. but it doesn't say nopadding or AES/CBC/nopadding. what I posted before was the full text mentioned from doc.

Comment: Let clear all, 1) it is CBC  2) the IV is zero all the time or it is given by the NFC 3) are there any encoding like base64? 4) Reasons for `BadPaddingException`  is usually a) IV is incorrect b) key is incorrect, c) data is corrupted. 5) You can create the zero IV as `byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];`

Comment: Did you repeat the test with different data?